# ios: media player is mute why?

Tags: ios

I have a iOS project with media video, but when I run this app the video are mute, help me please this is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MediaCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    MPMediaItem *item = [self.mediaItems objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    cell.tag = row;

    return cell;
}
- (void)loadMediaItemsForMediaType:(MPMediaType)mediaType

{

    MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

    NSNumber *mediaTypeNumber= [NSNumber numberWithInt:mediaType];

    MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate 
    predicateWithValue:mediaTypeNumber forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType];

    [query addFilterPredicate:predicate];

    self.mediaItems = [query items];
}
```

Comment: have you checked the mute switch on you device?

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing it on iPad? If yes, I have seen issues where app audio is muted if the side switch button is set to mute instead of "lock rotation" and you happen to click it. Check this wikihow to change it - http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Side-Switch-Function-On-an-iPad

Comment: If it solved your problem, can you accept this as the answer?